# Deriving the Laplace transform of $t$

Tags: laplace-transform

In deriving the Laplace transform of $t$, I'm not being able to grasp why the limit term go to 0:

$$\begin{align}
x(t)&=t\\
\\
\therefore\; X(s)&=\int_0^\infty t\cdot e^{-st}\;\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\left[\frac{-te^{-st}}{s}-\frac{e^{-st}}{s^2}\right]_0^\infty \quad \text{(using integ. by parts)}\\
&=\lim_{t \to \infty}\left(\frac{-te^{-st}}{s}\right)-\left(0-\frac{1}{s^2}\right)
\end{align}$$
We know that $$t \stackrel{\large \mathfrak{L}} \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{s^2} $$
$$\mathrm{Hence}\; \lim_{t \to \infty}\left(\frac{-te^{-st}}{s}\right)=0$$
But I can't fathom why it's so.

Comment: Use L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: $0\le te^{-st}=\frac{t}{e^{st}}\le \frac{t}{1+st+\frac12(st)^2}$ for $s>0$.  What is the limit as $t\to \infty$ of $\frac{t}{1+st+\frac12(st)^2}$?

Comment: It is obvious that $e^{-t}$ decays much more faster than $t$ as $t \to \infty$

Comment: Oooh now I get it. So stupid of me as I was trying to  L'Hôpital $\frac{-e^{-st}}{1/t}$ instead of the other way round. I still can't wrap my head around the "decays faster" logic though.